# How to show such a bar on iOS home screen?

Tags: ios, homescreen

Please take a look at this picture:

[image: iOS red bar at top]

How can this red bar at the top can be implemented? I think it must be displayed while the app is in the background. I have no idea what's that and how it's done.

Comment: but the app that shows that is not apple's

Comment: Can you give us that app's name?

Comment: This happens when an app has an active audio session (ie. is recording)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar it's named Sleep Cycle

Comment: @pNre can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: If the app is in the background and has background audio with recording, you'll see that  bar.

Comment: @Mikael well, do I understand you right that what I need to simulate such a behaviour is to start playing some fake file with silence on it instead of music and that's enough?

Comment: Does this app have recording functionality? I see this same case in **SleepBot** app as well. Just curious as Andrey..

Comment: @GenieWanted as far as I know it doesn't provide any functionality to record sound

Comment: hey @AndreyChernukha i getting this when my app going to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to make an app run in the background. These are called background modes. At the time of this writing there are total 5 basic background modes -- including audio, location, VoIP, Newsstand etc.

For Audio you get a red bar, for location you get no bar, for VoIP you get a green bar and so on.

Making the app run in the background has 2 steps:

1. Make the API call -- for location based app, call
   `CLLocationManager`, for audio start a audioSession.
2. Specify the background mode in the info.plist file

Also, there is a temporary background mode where the app runs for a finite time in the background to complete some initiated download.

Check out this detailed tutorial on all of the background modes:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

---

I am not sure what is your purpose here, but remember misusing the background mode may not make Apple quite happy when reviewing for Appstore submission.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable your audio background service in your info.plist with this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>    <array>
  <string>audio</string>    </array>
```

and if you play audio sounds in your app, or if you record, it will work automatically

Comment: what exactly should be used to play audio?

Comment: i'm not sure if you can use anything else.. but i used avAudioPlayer